# Azure Function Timer Triggered at exact time from database table

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, cron, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function (node.js) and a list of exact times (7:30, 8:05, etc.) in a database table. I would like to trigger the Azure Function at exact times using the database table.

Now my problems are

1. does timer trigger only take a single cron schedule?
2. can I maybe use environment variables to trigger at time1 (e.g. 7:30) then when it is done, change the environment variable to time2 (e.g. 8:05) in the code? So that it would run again at time2 (8:05)?
3. Can a different function (HTTP triggered) run my original function (timer triggered) and also change the environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does timer trigger only take a single cron schedule?
>   Yes, timer trigger could have only one cron expression

About dynamically cron expression, you could refer to this [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#configuration), the `ScheduleExpression` alows the setting in app settings. You could set with `"schedule": "%TriggerSchedule%"`.And define TriggerSchedule in your appsettings. Then modify your appsettings dynamically.

The other way is use the [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API)  to modify the function.json.

```
PUT https://{functionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/{pathToFunction.json}, Headers: If-Match: "*", Body: new function.json content
```

Then sync the function trigger.

```
POST https://{functionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/synctriggers
```

> Can a different function (HTTP triggered) run my original function
>   (timer triggered) and also change the environment variable?

You could invoke a HTTP trigger function in a Timer function, however the Azure Functions runtime configuration file is not writable. But as it runs App Service, you can manage those settings programmatically via [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/set-azurermwebapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0), [REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings), or through the [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-appsettings-set).

**Keep in mind** that changes to those settings will trigger a site restart

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Durable Functions for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers#usage-for-delay

There you can dynamically load the times from your database and create a new timer for the next execution. Once that one ran, create the next timer.

Basically you'll end up with an eternal orchestrator (which is ok): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations#periodic-work-example

Comment: It seems that Eternal Orchestration only does one activity in JS. I think continueAsNew is not working. [more info](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/issues/57)

Comment: I plan to do a Durable Function with the Usage for delay example. I was wondering if it only runs one instance of the function??? I'm afraid my functions would overlap (if running for days, two of it might run simultaneously) How to I kill other running functions???

Comment: I can't seem to make mongoDB work with Durable functions. Help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111661/using-durable-functions-in-azure-function-app-with-mongodb