# Using durable functions in azure function app with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure-functions

I have a mongoDB which contains the time where in my durable function should run (e.g. 8:00, 9:01, 10:20). Now I have my Orchestrator code below, nothing works inside the mongoClient.connect. Why???

```
const df = require("durable-functions");
const moment = require("moment");
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

module.exports = df.orchestrator(function*(context) {
    context.log("Getting time schedules in DB");
    var timeSched = [];
    var dbName = <dbName>;
    var collectionName = <collectionName>;

    var query = {id: "1"};
    try{
        mongoClient.connect(<mongoDB_connection_string>,{useNewUrlParser: true, authSource: dbName}, function (err, client) {
//Anything inside this does not log or work
            if(err){
                context.log(`Error occurred while connecting to DB ${err}`)
                return context.done();
            }else{
                context.log('MongoClient connected to DB');
            }
            var collection = client.db(dbName).collection(collectionName);
            collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                    timeSched.push(result[i].time); //e.g.8:00
                }
                client.close();
//This should log [8:00,9:01,10:01] but it does not log
                context.log(timeSched);
                context.done();
            });
        });
//This logs 0
        context.log(timeSched.length);
        for (let j = 0; j < timeSched.length; j++) {
            const deadline = moment.utc(context.df.currentUtcDateTime).add(3, 'minutes');
            yield context.df.createTimer(deadline.toDate());
            yield context.df.callActivity("ActivityFunction",timeSched[j]);
        }
        context.done();
    }catch(e){
        context.log(`Error ${e}`);
        context.done();
    }
});
```

Comment: I’m no expert in JavaScript functions but in C# you must not do any outbound or asynchronous calls in orchestrator functions, only in activity functions. I assume the same is true for JS functions.

Comment: @silent thanks for the heads up. I can't do it anyway. :( Would you recommend a solution to a scheduled function, where schedule is in a DB?

Comment: Have you tried query Mongo from within a activity function?

Comment: @silent, yeah. But I need the query for my orchestrator to know the number of activities to run.... So not sure how that would work.

Comment: again, I can't say to much about JS but I still assume C# is similar. There you would create an activity function that calls Mongo and returns any value (or in your case maybe your schedule times etc.) back to the orchestrator. With that your orchestrator can then set a timer for its next exectution

Comment: @silent, interesting. Any idea what the method is called in C#?

Comment: `CallActivityAsync()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#c And right there is also the JS example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#javascript-functions-2x-only

Comment: @Markkkkk Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to check if you can connect to DB first. Use console.log instead of context.log.

```
const df = require("durable-functions");
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
module.exports = df.orchestrator(function*(context) {
  var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
  mongoClient.connect(
    "mongodb://tonytest:78jst6Mh****.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true",
    function(err, client) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error occurred while connecting to DB ${err}`);
        return context.done();
      } else {
        console.log("MongoClient connected to DB");
      }
      client.close();
    }
  );
});
```

[image]

Try with `console.log(timeSched);` to output `timeSched`. Besides, when you execute `console.log(timeSched.length);`, `timeSched` hasn't been granted value. That's why you got `0`;